# Use Parameter In OPENROWSET Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

> I am creating an stored procedure in which I am calling an another
>   stored procedure(This procedure is returned lot of columns and I want
>   only one column value So I can't create temp table to store values)
>   using `OPENROWSET`.
>
> When I am use following then it's alright

```
declare @AgencyID int=15,@PatientID int=3701
SELECT a.PrimaryInsuredName 
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',  
    'Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=yes',
    'exec USP_Billing_GetPatientWithInsurence 3701,15') AS a;
```

> It's working fine. But I want to pass parameters for calling
>   `USP_Billing_GetPatientWithInsurence` because values will be dynamic.
>   So I use following code

```
 declare @AgencyID int=15,@PatientID int=3701
    SELECT a.PrimaryInsuredName 
        FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',  
        'Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=yes',
        'exec USP_Billing_GetPatientWithInsurence '+ @PatientID +','+ @AgencyID+'') AS a;
```

> But it's not working When I run this query then an error occurred
>   `Incorrect syntax near '+'.` I don't know why this is coming. Please
>   provide a solution to this. I googled also for this but can't found a
>   proper solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have to make your entire SELECT string dynamic:

```
 declare @AgencyID int=15,@PatientID int=3701
DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(max)='
    SELECT a.PrimaryInsuredName 
        FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',  
        ''Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=yes'',
        ''exec USP_Billing_GetPatientWithInsurence '+ CAST(@PatientID AS varchar(15)) +','+ CAST(@AgencyID AS varchar(15)) +''') AS a';
EXECUTE(@SQLStr);
```